# Are there rules in using assembly language registers

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, cpu-registers, calling-convention

Assembly language is quite straight forward but I am confused on how to use registers for example:

```
section .data    

msg db "Hello, world!",0xa  
len equ $ - msg 

section .text    


global _start   

_start:

;write our string to stdout

mov edx,len 
mov ecx,msg 
mov eax,4 
int 0x80        

;and exit

mov ebx,0   
mov eax,1 
int 0x80
```

Its working fine but when i change the code to:

```
section .data    

msg db "Hello, world!",0xa  
len equ $ - msg 

section .text    


global _start   

_start:

;write our string to stdout

mov ebx,len 
mov edx,msg 
mov eax,4 
int 0x80    

;and exit

mov ebx,0   
mov eax,1 
int 0x80
```

It will compile but it will not display `'Hello, World'`. All I did was change the register for `len` and `msg`. Is there a convention on what register must contain?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it matters what registers are used when executing a syscall. `eax` holds the number of the syscall (in this case 4), and `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `esi`, `edi` and `ebp` hold the argumens of the syscall in that order. The first argument has to be stored in `ebx`, the second in `ecx`, and so on, it doesn't make sense otherwise.

[Look here](http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html) for a list of Linux syscalls. As you can see, syscall number 4 is `sys_write`:

`ssize_t sys_write(unsigned int fd, const char * buf, size_t count)`

Therefore your registers must be set up as so:

- `eax` - syscall number = 4 for `sys_write`
- `ebx` - `fd` = file descriptor, 1 for `stdout`
- `ecx` - `buf` = pointer to your string (`msg` in your code)
- `edx` - `count` = amount of characters to print (`len` in your code)

**EDIT:** [Here's another table](http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html) with what each register should be filled with for specific syscalls. These two links also contain more information about syscalls that might be worth a read:

- http://freebsd.unixtech.be/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html
- http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html

Comment: So the setup of register must be in order eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi, edi, ebp. What if i use ebp to hold the number of syscall, Therefore the order of the register is ebp, edi, esi, edx, ecx, ebx, eax to make sense?

Comment: @the_transltr: `eax` is for holding the syscall number, `ebx` for the first argument, `ecx` for the second argument, `edx` for the third argument, etc. This is how the syscall expects the arguments to be passed. There's no "order", that's just how it is.